# How do you set a title for a PDF in Powerbuilder that was added using an OLE Control?

Tags: pdf, powerbuilder, ole

In Powerbuilder I've added a PDF to a window using the OLE Control.  I've added a value in the DisplayName field, but when I run the program, the PDF opens but the title displays something completely different.  It's as if it takes some of the text in the PDF as the title instead of what I've set in the displayname field.  Is there somewhere else I need to set the title of the PDF?

Comment: The answer is specific to the PDF creator you have. I think if you check their documentation you'll find your answer.

Comment: @RichBianco All I’m using is Microsoft Word to save the word document as a PDF. And I’m saving it as ‘document release notes v6.12’ yet when it opens the title says ‘document v4’ which is not displayed anywhere through the document

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the direction of a person that commented on my post, I was able to find that I can update the metadata in Word, then generate the PDF.